# Table (or CDS) Field DisplayFormat

Tags: delphi, displayformat

When adding persistent fields of a dataset using the Fields Editor, the field names are concatenated to the dataset as `TableMyField`, I can then access the persistent field's `DisplayFormat` property in my code as:

```
TableMyField.DisplayFormat
```

However, if I don't use the Fields Editor and don't use persistent fields, how can I access the `DisplayFormat` property at run time?

Comment: Dataset's `TField` inherits `DisplayFormat` from its definition, so set it up right for the field in your case.

Comment: @Victoria not sure if this is true. TField decedents implement displayformat for each decending classe's purpose. OP would need to cast, example:  `TFloatFIeld(dataset.fieldbyname('Cost')).displayformat := '#,###.00'`  etc.

Comment: @John, sorry, I missed the word _descendants_. But they inherit that from definition, or am I wrong (no Delphi by hand)? I haven't checked that, but it's the only logical source I can think of. And what would be wrong on the approach that you've shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the DisplayFormat property is contained in descending classes of TField, you'd need to cast at runtime. You can do this a couple of different ways.

```
TNumericField(Dataset.Fieldbyname('CostPrice')).DisplayFormat := '#,###.00';

(Dataset.fieldbyname('CostPrice') as TNumericField).DisplayFormat := '#,###.00';

TNumericField(Dataset.fields[0]).DisplayFormat := '#,###.00';
```

Comment: That Works Perfectly Thank you